# Como poner ambos métodos en una linea JAVA

Tags: java

quisiera saber si podrian explicarme o al menos decirme si es posible poder asignar ambos metodos en una sola linea, como tengo ahora es de la forma siguiente:

```
    Metodos colores = new Metodos();
    Metodos operacion = new Metodos();
```

la duda es si ambos pueden estar en una misma linea, por ejemplo:

```
    Metodos colores, operacion = new Metodos();
```

Como puse arriba me dice que no se asigna o que no es usado, a pesar de que se esta usando

Comment: Me parece que esto es definicion de variables, y lo mismo te pasaria si pusieras int A,B=3.. A vale el valor por defecto de un int no? No se si la interfaz te deja hacer Metodos colores = operacion = new Metodos()?

Comment: Colores no esta creado y operación si, ya que operación es la única variable que se instanció con el constructor.

Comment: Te podrias explayar un poco mas? por favor, mira, ambos estando linea por linea funcionan correctamente y estan en uso, en cambio si los intento separar por comas da error en donde se tendria que utilizar colores u operacion, dependiendo de cual lo escriba primero

Comment: Colores no esta creado, el igual no es para la linea, es para cada variable.

Comment: En ese caso, si o si tendrian que ir individualmente por linea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto es incorrecto:

```
  Metodos colores, operacion = new Metodos();
```

La única forma de realizar lo que deseas es :

```
Metodos colores = new Metodos(), operacion = new Metodos();
```

debes realizarlo de esta forma y que las clases deben ser inicializadas.

Comment: Excelente!! eso es lo que buscaba, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Listo, listo. Gracias! lo mismo hice para los scanner, ahora si ya quedo legible todo jajaj

Comment: Espera si usas la clase Scanner, no es necesario definir la más de una vez, con una es suficiente :).

Comment: Scanner numero = new Scanner(System.in),
                numeroSecundario = new Scanner(System.in),
                pregunta = new Scanner(System.in); asi quedo!

Comment: @ScarK no amigo, preferentemente,en el caso de la clase Scanner puedes crear solo una instancia y esta usarla para obtener datos introducidos por el usuario.

Comment: Te refieres con que basta crear uno solo para todo el programa? estoy haciendo una calculadora, es mi primer proyecto

Comment: @ScarK al menos en una misma clase solo necesitarías una instancia de Scanner.

Comment: Logre reducir a 2, uno aparte necesito ya que es para tipo string, los demás son int, double. Al intentar poner todo junto me dio error

Comment: Tal vez hay un detalle en tu programa, revisa las respuestas, hay ejemplos donde se definen varios tipos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542833/different-java-scanner-for-input-of-different-types

Comment: Ya quedo, leí lo que mandaste y logre implementarlo, gracias! saludos

Comment: Excelente @ScarK saludos!